# How to do Test Driven Development right way?

Tags: java, tdd

I have read about TDD and I tried it on my new project.

[image: TDD cycle]

I understand that in TDD it is like blackbox testing , ie it matters **what** rather than **how**.So, 
I concluded and stopped testing private methods after reading about it on many posts as it is not correct way.

However, I failed to do it due to these reasons.

I will show you by example :
I have a program that reads a text paragraph so I wrote something like this in my test method (for tdd step1).

```
/*
My program reads a textual paragraph from file and saves it to my custom paragraph object; 
*/
```

So accordingly I made this method to create the **RED** case.

```
public void paragraphMustNotBeNullTest(){
File f = new File("some path")
 ParagraphReader reader= new ParagraphReader();
 reader.read();
assertNotNull("my custom paragraph is null",reader.getCustomParagraph());
}
```

I have written following code:

```
package com.olabs.reader;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.olabs.models.OlabsParagraph;

public class Para {


    private String paragraphText = null;
    private Paragraph oParagraph = null;

    public Paragraph getCustomParagraph() {
        return oParagraph;
    }
    public void setoParagraph(Paragraph oParagraph) {
        this.oParagraph = oParagraph;
    }

    public void read() {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("abc......");
//      ..
        String text = is.read(); // assume I got text read from file.
        this.paragraphText = text;
    }


    private void createCustomParagraph()
    {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.setText(paragraphText);
        p.setId(1);
        p.setType("Story");
        ...........
    }

    private void countWords()
    {
        // counting words in paragraph logic
    }


}
```

Now the problem is I know beforehand that I will be using **countingwords** and **createCustomParagraph** as private methods.

So, in that cases should I go with:

1. creating them as public and follow tdd cycle.
2. make them private.
3. delete the tests for them(as the methods are now private and inaccessible for tests).
   I think this is quite cumbersome and incorrect way to do tdd.

I am confused about this.Everyone says write code only after you write a failing test, but here if I know I am going to write a **private method** then how will I do this?

I request you to correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Also if possible give some real example...

Also, I fear that most of the time I will be **editing tests or removing them** due to access specifiers problems or refactoring ...

Note : This is **not** a duplicate question. I don't have good answer for realtime situations.In all examples I have seen, they show only a single class with default or public access specifiers, so they really don't show how exactly to work in realtime project.

Comment: Your private methods are (directly or indirectly) called by some public methods. You test the public methods. Ergo, you test the private methods (indirectly). What exactly confuses you?

Comment: So do you mean reader.read(); method call is enough ? ie I will go on writing private methods, I will not go through red green yellow cycle for these new private methods(i assume on that instant that it should be private) i create?

Comment: If you introduce a new (and most likely buggy) private method (that is used by a public method), write a test that fails (and does so because the private method is not working correctly).

Comment: @Turing85 so should I assume that when i have exposed my class with read() method, it is evident that other methods will be private (if no other public interface is required) .I dont need test cases for any of these methods(private ones). I will now just test public variables in that class after calling read() method, ie if they are fine and my read() method is printing write op.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my personal experience, you are testing the class and the interface to the class by the rest of your application.
Your TDD test cases should be written against the public methods of your class. The point is to test that when stimulated, the class outputs the desired results to pass your test criteria. Internal private methods will be tested as a part of the public interface testing, but the goal is to verify that the publicly accessible interface is working.
You say you know ahead of time that the private methods will be used, but if someone refactors how things are done in the class without changing the external behavior you will still be able to use your existing tests and verify that refactoring has not broken a previously working method.

Comment: does it mean that when i write a public method like reader.read(), i can go on writing other methods inside the reader class(i assume they will be private because I am done writing public method read) without following tdd cycle for them (ie red greem yellow for each method)as my only public method in this case (according to my assumption and obvious calling method will be read()) ..

Comment: The purpose of your class is to provide the capabilities of the public methods. Everything happening inside the class that is private is supporting the public methods. If you are using the black box approach, the inside implementation can be anything as long as the public functionality is passing the tests.

Comment: Should I conclude that The public interface will be created , refactored and decomposed to private methods ... and only that public method will be called in tests. I am not sure if I am doing tdd right way.

Comment: An external test can only call your public methods. There are numerous ways to implement those methods. You could be doing all of the processing in the public method or calling a private method. The point is that from the outside it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If a method is an implementation detail of the primary thing you're building which ought to remain private, that doesn't mean there's no way to write a test for it. You can make that functionality part of another class where it can be public, writing tests that exercise it directly, then call that privately from the primary thing. That way you can test the private methods, no tests get deleted, and you don't have to go through contortions testing something indirectly when the thing using it may not expose access to everything you want to test. And now instead of having private methods that are concealed bits of gnarly code, you have well-tested building blocks ready for reuse somewhere else.

Comment: in this case dont you think you are modifying the design for sake of tests.Can you post an example?

Comment: @swapyonubuntu: that's ok, that's why they call it TDD. maybe later.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. I also asked it many times. And in general the answers said that you have to think about unit tests which goes before an implementation of main functionality like about **frames**. These frames strictly define the functionality.

So you even may don't know about private methods before you are going to implement some particular classes. But since you have a set of **RED** tests, the one thing you must do is to make them green. Doesn't matter how you will do it (public or private methods).

A goal number one is to write minimum lines of code, which **should be covered** by the unit tests. I covered [TDD topic](http://fruzenshtein.com/java-tdd-with-junit-example-1/) more deeply on my blog.